# "Stops" in Highcharts polar chart column?

Tags: highcharts, visualization

We want to achieve the same as "stops" (like in solid gauge), where we can define values from 0-5 is red, 6 and 7 is yellow, and 8 is green for each column in a Highcharts polar chart.
But stops, that we have tried, is displaying a gradient for the whole column independent of value.. not able to define colours for each column based on specific value.

Only option I see so far is to set colour based on data directly. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/buzLywrx/3/
That is:

```
data: [{ y: 8, color: 'green'}, { y: 7, color: 'green'}, { y: 6, color: 'yellow'}, { y: 5, color: 'yellow'}, { y: 4, color: 'red'}, { y: 3, color: 'green'}, { y: 2, color: 'red'}, { y: 1, color: 'red'}],
```

We are displaying a mean, so the data can actually be any number (with two decimals) between 0-100.

What is the best option to achieve column colour based on a value range?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on each point in the serie and update color by condition.

```
var color;
    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, data){
        if(data.y<4) {
           color = 'red';
        } else if((data.y>4) && (data.y <6)) {
                color = 'yellow';
        } else if(data.y > 6) { 
                color = 'orange';
        }

        data.update({
                color: color
        });
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/buzLywrx/4/